# Angular custom module cannot be loaded

Tags: angular, angular-components

Probably obvious for most, but I still cannot find it out myself.

I have an angular application and the following relevant files

```
app/app.module.ts
app/dashboard/dashboard.component.html
app/dashboard/stats-tile/stats-tile.component.html
```

I generated the stats-tile component with ng generate so in the app.module.ts its imported and also in the declarations:

```
//app.module.ts
declarations: [
AppComponent,
TournamentSearchComponent,
DashboardComponent,
StatsTileComponent
],
```

Now I want to show the stats-tile component

```
//dashboard.component.html
<app-dashboard-stats-tile></app-dashboard-stats-tile>
```

I get:

```
Error: Template parse errors:
'app-dashboard-stats-tile' is not a known element:
```

What am I doing wrong. I am able to use another component i generated in the app component. is there some difference when I generate it in a subfolder?
I am a bit new to angular but my understanding is that everything imported/declared in app.module.ts is available to the whole app.

Comment: Is dashboard component also declared in the `AppModule`?

Comment: Could you please provide more snippets for app.module, Host component and stats-tile component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess, based on the names of the files, is that you have used the wrong name here:

```html
<app-dashboard-stats-tile></app-dashboard-stats-tile>
```

The name of this component `.ts` file would be "dashboard-stats-tile.ts".

You might want to replace this line with:

```html
<app-stats-tile></app-stats-tile>
```

Comment: Correct, just saw it too. I thought the selector was always kind of the path and i didnt know I find it in the component.ts selector: 'app-stats-tile',